# Error creating Calendly webhook subscription with .Net HttpClient()

Tags: c#, curl, dotnet-httpclient, calendly

I am trying to Create a webhook subscription with .net HttpClient() for Calendly

https://developer.calendly.com/docs/webhook-subscriptions

I am attempting to convert this Curl command to .Net

```
curl --header "X-TOKEN: <your_token>" --data "url=https://blah.foo/bar&events[]=invitee.created&events[]=invitee.canceled" https://calendly.com/api/v1/hooks
```

Here is my .Net code:

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostCreateWebhookSubscription()
{
    var client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri("https://calendly.com")};
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/v1/hooks/");
    var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("url",
            "https://requestb.in/17ruxqh1&events[]=invitee.created&events[]=invitee.canceled")
    };
    request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") {CharSet = "UTF-8"};
    request.Content.Headers.Add("X-TOKEN", "<my_calendly_token>");
    return await client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

I get this error 422 error, but unable to figure out what to change to make this work.

getting error Unprocessable Entity

{"type":"validation_error","message":"Validation failed","errors":{"events":["can't be blank"]}}

I am able to run the Curl command and it works fine from the same machine, so I know that is working.

I created a .net HttpClient call to test the basic Token, which worked fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally came back this which figured it out as soon as I looked at the code again.

Originally I was looking at the whole URL as one big string, but did not realize at first the & symbol which was separating the values to pass.

The bad code below:

```
var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("url",
        "https://requestb.in/17ruxqh1&events[]=invitee.created&events[]=invitee.canceled")
};
```

Should have been changed to this seperating each value from their documentation:

```
var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("url","https://requestb.in/17ruxqh1"),
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("events[]","invitee.created"),
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("events[]","invitee.canceled")
};
```

So for those that want to use .Net to create webhook subscriptions with Calendly here is a full TestMethod code to try it out.  Just replace the first parameter with your requestb.in or post url.  Also put in your Calendly api key.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateCalendlyWebhookSubscription()
    {
        var task = PostCreateWebhookSubscription();
        task.Wait();
        var response = task.Result;
        var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }

    private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostCreateWebhookSubscription()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri("https://calendly.com")};
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/v1/hooks/");
        var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("url","https://requestb.in/17ruxqh1"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("events[]","invitee.created"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("events[]","invitee.canceled")
        };
        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") {CharSet = "UTF-8"};
        request.Content.Headers.Add("X-TOKEN", "<your Calendly ApiKey>");
        return await client.SendAsync(request);
    }
```

Hope this helps somebody!